# Sine wave with a frequency which varies according to a sine wave?

Tags: trigonometry

How would you create a sine wave with a frequency which varies according to a sine wave? In other words, the frequency starts at some minimum value, then gradually increases to a maximum value, then gradually decreases back down to the minimum value, and so on. In this instance, the amplitude should remain constant. Only the frequency fluctuates.

I've tried playing around with variations of sin(sin(x)) and have even tried using modulo arithmetic, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Would something like $x \mapsto \sin(8 x + 4 \sin x)$ suit your needs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation

Comment: @TravisWillse Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for! As a follow up question, how do I control the overall period? It seems that no matter what I set the numbers to (8 and 4 in your example), the overall period remains stuck at 2pi.

Comment: You can always dilate the graph of a function horizontally by replacing $x \mapsto \lambda x$ for some $\lambda > 0$. Notice that my answer only gives a particular pattern of modulation, but many more patterns are possible. See the formula in the link that Dan Uznanski provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varying the instantaneous frequency of a sine wave is the basis of frequently modulation, the method used to encode signals for FM radio. If $\nu_c$ is the baseline angular frequency (the carrier angular frequency), the information $x(t)$ can be encoded via the function
$$y(t) = A \cos \left(\nu_c t + \nu_\Delta \int_0^t x(\tau) \,d\tau \right) .$$ Here $A > 0$ is the amplitude and $\nu_\Delta$ is a convenient normalizing frequency.

To satisfying the condition "the frequency starts at some minimum value, then gradually increases to a maximum value, then gradually decreases back down to the minimum value, and so on," we can choose the signal $x(t)$ itself to be sinusoidal, e.g., take $x(\tau) = \cos \nu_m t$, for some angular frequency $nu_m$, which yields $\int_0^t x(\tau) \,d\tau = \frac{1}{\nu_m} \sin \nu_m t$, giving
$$y(t) = A \cos \left(\nu_c t + \frac{\nu_\Delta}{\nu_m} \sin \nu_m t\right).$$

*Figure 1. Two periods of a signal encoding the sinusoidal information $x(t)$ with $A = 1, \nu_c = 6, \nu_\Delta = 3, \nu_m = 1$.*

[image]